# How to play ringtone in timePicker

Tags: android, timepicker, ringtone

I am trying to build an alert clock app.  The `TimePicker` is working, but how can I get it to do something after selecting the time?  I am trying to play ringtone action.

This is the `TimePicker` class:

```
public  class TimePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {

private  int hours;
private  int minutes;
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    int min = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

    return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, hour, min,
            DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));

}

@Override
public void onTimeSet(android.widget.TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
    hours = hourOfDay;
    minutes = minute;

    if(hours == Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY && minutes == Calendar.MINUTE){
        Uri notification = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getContext(), notification);
        r.play();
    }
}
```

}

This is the button to activate the TimePicker:

```
timePicker = (Button)findViewById(R.id.TimePickerButton);

timePicker.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        DialogFragment newFragment = new TimePickerFragment();
        newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "pickerTime");

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must remove

```
if(hours == Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY && minutes == Calendar.MINUTE){
}
```

Comment: thanks man! it's working!!
but why the rington is playing immediately, don't matter the time i choose?

Comment: If you want clock scheduling try https://www.google.com/search?q=android+set+alarm+scheduled&oq=android+set+alarm+scheduled&aqs=chrome..69i57.23635j0j4&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8#q=android+alarm+clock+code+example